# agm polygon get paths

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular5, angular-google-maps

I am using [angular google map](https://angular-maps.com/)

and I have an editable polygon in my template like following

```
<agm-map [latitude]="34"  [longitude]="53">
  <agm-polygon #polygon id="polygon" (polyMouseUp)="OnMouseUp($event)"  [paths]="paths"  [editable]="true"></agm-polygon>
</agm-map>
```

and in my typescript file I have

```
export class DistrictComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('polygon') polygon:ElementRef;
  constructor(
    private el:ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  paths = [
    {lat:34.0214,lng:50.1654},
    {lat:34.023414,lng:50.23454},
    {lat:34.45214,lng:50.45654},
    {lat:34.5634,lng:50.345634},
    {lat:34.45614,lng:50.14654}
  ]



}
```

how should I access to my path when I edited polygon by dragging and dropping points or by moving polygon?